# Incorrect French translation for Surname

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

The terms 'Surname' and 'Name' are translated in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into  `app >locale >fr_FR >Mage_Customer.csv` the correct translation for `Surname` is `Nom` and not `Prénom`.
The same for `Name`: its translation is `Prénom` and not `Nom`.